# Wiimote on PC with GlovePIE and Wiinremote

Tags: scripting, game-development, infrared, wiimote

First off, I hope this is the right place to post this. I am new, and Stack Exchange was the first site I thought of for this question. After reading the "How to Ask" page here, I don't see a better place. Let me know if I'm missing something and there's a place more suited for this question.
My question here, with background info below: Does anyone know how to use only pitch and roll for a mouse in GlovePIE, without yaw and IR?

Background: basically, I want to use my wiimote for mouse + WASD for PC gaming, but I cannot use an IR sensor bar. (I am CADding around the wiimote for a project and this material will end up obstructing the signal.) I have at my disposal: an RVL-036 wiimote and a broadcomm bluetooth dongle with a hacked Toshiba stack, a used RVL-003 wiimote I bought when the 036 didn't pan out, Wiinremote, and GlovePIE.

GlovePIE doesn't work with the 036 wiimote, and neither does Wiinremote even though I expected it to. With the 003, Wiinremote gives me perfect mouse movement using pitch and roll (I hear yaw needs an IR sensor). The problem is: I can set keys in Wiinremote such as Up on the D-pad to W on the keyboard, Left to A, and Down to S, but they only work in web browsers and such and not in-game.
My focus is now on GlovePIE scripts because I hear it does a good job in-game getting wiimote buttons to act as keyboard keys. (I first tried lednerg's motionplus script, but obviously I get "motion plus NOT DETECTED" in the debug field. I can click with the script running, but I just can't pan the cursor around.) I have looked around for mouse scripts so that I can add my own WASD key assignments, but every script I have found uses an IR sensor bar. I know it must be possible to use only roll and pitch for a mouse in GlovePIE--because Wiinremote handles it beautifully--but I have unsuccessfully tried looking for wii-specific GlovePIE tutorials and I don't understand the general syntax or how to call on the wiimote in GlovePIE.
I basically want to do exactly what Wiinremote does but in GlovePIE in the hopes of getting keys to work in-game.

My question: does anyone know how to use only pitch and roll for a mouse or know how I can familiarize myself with GlovePIE's language to do it myself?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for https://superuser.com/.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I don't know if this would be the right site. SO is primarily a coding help website, where we help you debug **your** code. We aren't here to write it for you, and while we can give suggestions, it not the primary purpose of Stack Overflow. Again, interesting question though.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, nwk and Tim. I posted on Super User. But I think I just answered my own question anyway. I found a stupidly simple solution: run GlovePIE and Wiinremote simultaneously, GlovePIE for buttons and Wiinremote for the mouse. *facepalm*
GlovePIE's syntax seems simple enough from others' button assignment scripts, as long as I stay away from mouse scripting.